# How to count jsonb object keys in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to find which of the jsonb keys are the most popular ones in my `data` field. I was able to get names of all keys with this query:

```
select jsonb_object_keys(data) as key
from client 
group by key;
```

When I try to add a count like I normally do:

```
select jsonb_object_keys(data) as key, count(jsonb_object_keys(data))
from client 
group by key;
```

I receive this error:

```
ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
```

Is there a way to count distinct keys of jsonb object?

Sample data:

```
data
{"a": "xyz"}
{"b": "assa", "c": "134323"}
{"c": "123"}
{"c": "12324", "a": "xysaz"}
```

Desired output:

```
key count(key)
a   2
b   1  
c   3
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jsonb_object_keys` is a set returning function -- basically a table.  You want to refer to it in the `FROM` clause, so I recommend:

```
select k as key, count(*)
from client c cross join lateral
     jsonb_object_keys(c.data) k
group by k;
```

The `lateral` is actually optional.  However, I much prefer including it because otherwise the parsing is awkward (why does `c.data` resolve correctly?).

Comment: honestly, this was some black magic. i never new about lateral and this has changed my life. so awesome. thank you!